# Use SSH to connect with PC in local network

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet

I want to access the PC's connected in local network. I have installed the **nmap**.

I want to connect with other PC using SSH.

Can anyone help me regarding this??

Comment: What does nmap have to do with it? What OS are the systems running? Have you tried `ssh user@1.2.3.4` where `1.2.3.4` is the IP of the target machine?

Answer (score 1):

The machine **from** which you want to connect via `ssh` needs a ssh-client. If you're using Ubuntu, this client is installed by default.

All the machines **to** which you want to connect need a ssh-server installed and running. Under Ubuntu, you may install the `openssh-server` via the software Center or through `apt-get install`.

This will allow to login remotely.

If you want more comfort, create a `/home/YOURNAME/.ssh` file with entries for the remote machines you want to connect to. The entries will look like this:

```
Host OTHERMACHINE
HostName OTHERHOSTNAME
User OTHERUSER
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Using such a file will allow to `ssh` to `OTHERMACHINE` simply by typing `ssh OTHERMACHINE`, even when the usernames differ on client and server.